# Adding Merchant domains for Apple Pay Payment Processing on the Web

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, applepay, payfort, applepayjs

I am trying to implement Apple Pay on the web
As per the documentation after creating the merchant id and  Apple Pay Payment Processing Certificate I am required to add Merchant Domains as well as  Apple Pay Merchant Identity Certificate. I did create merchant id and  Apple Pay Payment Processing Certificate

I have trouble with add  Merchant Domains. Add Merchant Domains button greyed out the roles and permissions of my account is admin
 [Apple Pay Payment Processing Certificate screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cX2SQ.png) 
[image: Add Merchant Domains button greyed out screenshot]

Comment: Is that screenshot from the Apple part of the process?  Are you not using Stripe's Payment Request Button? https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button

Comment: Yes, Apple part I have answered my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the solution to my issue, the issue was with accepting Apple pay terms and conditions it only appears the first time when you create a merchant id.