# add merchant domain Apple Pay processing on the app

Tags: ios, swift, applepay

I'm trying to implement Apple Pay on iOS app, and after creating the merchant id and Apple Pay Payment Processing Certificate I am required to add Merchant Domains as well as Apple Pay Merchant Identity Certificate.but the "add domain" button isn't active.

[image]

[image]

If you know how to solve this problem, please let me know. thanks in advance for your reply!

I saw a similar question here:
[Adding Merchant domains for Apple Pay Payment Processing on the Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59726006/adding-merchant-domains-for-apple-pay-payment-processing-on-the-web)

but the answer didn't help me:

"accepting Apple pay terms and conditions it only appears the first time when you create a merchant id."

the button is still inactive